# display generated report via jaspereports on browser

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

i'm developping a struts2 app,and i want to show up my generated report on browser. i've succefully generate my report on disk.but now i want to see it at browser.here is some code.

my index.jsp

```
<body>
<a href="HTML.action">Reporting</a>
</body>
```

my action DataBeanList

```
public class DataBeanList extends ActionSupport {

      public ArrayList<DataBean> getDataBeanList() {
     ArrayList<DataBean> dataBeanList = new ArrayList<DataBean>();

      dataBeanList.add(produce("Manisha", "India"));
      dataBeanList.add(produce("Dennis Ritchie", "USA"));
      dataBeanList.add(produce("V.Anand", "India"));
      dataBeanList.add(produce("Shrinath", "California"));
      dataBeanList.add(produce("issam", "casa"));

      return dataBeanList;
   }

   /**
    * This method returns a DataBean object,
    * with name and country set in it.
    */
   private DataBean produce(String name, String country) {
      DataBean dataBean = new DataBean();
      dataBean.setName(name);
      dataBean.setCountry(country);
      return dataBean;
   }


public void exporte(){

String sourceFileName = "D://Test/workspace/ztest/WebContent/reports/jasper_report_template.jasper";
               // + "test/jasper_report_template.jasper";
        //D:\Test\workspace\ztest\WebContent\reports
          String printFileName = null;
          DataBeanList DataBeanList = new DataBeanList();
          ArrayList dataList = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList();
          JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource =
             new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);

          Map parameters = new HashMap();
          try {
             printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(sourceFileName,
                parameters, beanColDataSource);
             if (printFileName != null) {
                /**
                 * 1- export to PDF
                 */
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printFileName,
                      "D://sample_report.pdf");


             }
          } catch (JRException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }    
}
```

Comment: Export report to stream and use Struts2 `stream` result.

Comment: @AleksandrM,thanks for reply, but i did not understand your approach,is there a link.or could you explain to me more

Comment: What exactly? See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/stream-result.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM, if you see my action i was exporting my report in disk like this JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printFileName,
                      "D://sample_report.pdf");  So how to retreive that report and display it on browser or display it on browser without exporting to hard disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all export you report to stream, something like that:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
            parameters, beanDataSource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, out);
```

Then convert output stream to input stream and assign it inside your action to `inputStream` variable with getters/setters. And configure action to use `stream` result.

```
<action ...>
  <result type="stream">
    <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="report.pdf"</param>
  </result>
</action>
```